# express node-http-proxy , proxy.proxyRequest to https server?

Tags: node.js, https, express, node-http-proxy

Is it possible to use the  node-http-prox module and proxy.proxyRequest to a https server?
I tried to do the following but doesnt seem to work.

```
app.get('/c/users/moreuser', function(req, res) {
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
        host: 'api.example.com',
        port: 80,
        https: true
    });
});
```

doing this i dont get any response from the server. But i can get response directly from the server.

Answer (score 1):

try `port: 443`, which is the default port for HTTPS.

Comment: doesnt work. The api is on port 80 even if its https.